# how to show/measure depth and threshold of a tibco queue/topics in java, spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, jms, tibco-topic

I want to show eit tibco jms queue depth and threshold in java.
Is anyone has sample example of how to show queue depth and threshold.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include tibjmsadmin.jar in your build path and then you can do this:

```
 TibjmsAdmin admin = new TibjmsAdmin(server, user, password);
 int numMsgs = admin.getQueues("Q1")[0].getPendingMessageCount();
```

Not sure what you mean by 'threshold' but maybe try getMaxMsgs()

Comment: Thanks Axel.. But Tibco jms admin jar is not available on net and also I am using spring boot. So my maven doesn't have admin dependency.

Comment: yeah, you have to have tibjmsadmin.jar - do you have an EMS server installation ? There you should find this jar. Otherwise, you could create a standard JMS QueueBrowser and then run that from start to finish and count - but that could be very slow.